# Debian 11 ignores xorg.conf

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia

When I updated Debian from 10 to 11, Debian began ignoring my customized `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (which worked fine previously), I also made a copy of the same file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf`.

The change I'm trying to accomplish is to have my second monitor x-offsets of 1920px, and when I apply this change from Nvidia settings it works fine, it's just that something resets every boot.

It is also interesting that the change is in effect on the logging screen but immediately reset by something once logged in...

While searching for a solution I found about adding `Option "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x3322` to the device options for both files, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is also interesting that the change is in effect on the logging screen but immediately reset by something once logged in...

This probably means the `xorg.conf` *is* initially taking effect, but once your desktop environment starts up, it uses the XRANDR protocol extension to override it.

If you are using a XRANDR-aware desktop environment, you should use the settings in `xorg.conf[.d]` for the login screen setup only, and use the desktop environment's settings tools to set your logged-in display configuration.

`Option "RegistryDwords"` is not documented by NVidia, meaning that no promises whatsoever are made on its availability. It may have been available on some past versions; it may again become available on some future version; but it may not actually be usable in your current driver version.

Comment: With "desktop environment settings tools" you mean Display?

Comment: In KDE, it's System Settings -> Display and Monitor. Are you using Debian's default GNOME desktop, or something else?

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon

Comment: Regardless, I re-logged-in, and changing of Display settings worked. Thank you, this is something that troubled me for a few days.

Comment: i tried GNOME, Cinnamon, with multiple times of installation but still stuck on boot after installed everything. Is it similar trouble with this...? @Chlodio

Comment: @gumuruh That sounds like a different issue